# Bike Help describing

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

[image]
What type of bike is this? When was it made? Also what model is it?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Mason. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. That's really not a very good photo of the bike; it mostly shows a guy and a post. Help us to help you!

Comment: It's a Specialized mountain bike.  Probably not more than 10 years old.

Comment: I'd guess closer to 15+  -- The levers seem to say XTR on them, and there are V-brakes. Do you know when the picture was taken?

Comment: If you want to identify a bike and the brand name is visible, Googling for "[brand name] bike" is always going to be a good first step. It would be helpful to let us know what research you've already done so that people don't spend time repeating your efforts.

Comment: Sadly the flags "unclear" and "too broad" don't really apply, do we need a "not enough information, OP non-responsive" flag?

Comment: My guess is a Specialized Stolen : P

Answer (score -2):

That is a "full suspension" mountain bike frame from a company called "Specialized"

I can't identify the exact model - you can browse their website   https://www.specialized.com/ as well as I can.

At a guess, its a Camber or a Stumpjumper, but from some other year.

Comment: Please see [answer], especially the part that says *Answer well-asked questions*.

Comment: @andy256 Its not great, but is better than many identify-this-bike questions.  At least Mason included a photo.